# Meteor OAuth login on Android DDP

Tags: android, meteor, oauth, ddp

How would one use OAuth login with any of the Android DDPs for Meteor like

- https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP
- https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client

The current official OAuth flow in Meteor is tightly coupled to the browser. We should be able to complete the login flow by supplying the OAuth access tokens to the Meteor API through the DDPs, but there is no official documentation for this.

I searched a lot on this topic but could not find anything for a solution. Do I need to hack into the Meteor core packages to achieve such basic functionality? This seems very trivial.